# PBEWithSHAAnd128BitRC4 implementation in java

Tags: java, security

I am using IBM JRE and i want to implement PBEWithSHAAnd128BitRC4 algorothm for my cipher so which alorithm should i use for my SecretKeyFactory and SecretKeySpec ,below is the secret key supporting algos which i got from provider.getInfo() methode for IBMJCE provider.

```
Cipher algorithms                  : Blowfish, AES, DES, TripleDES, PBEWithMD2AndDES, 
                                       PBEWithMD2AndTripleDES, PBEWithMD2AndRC2, 
                                       PBEWithMD5AndDES, PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES, 
                                       PBEWithMD5AndRC2, PBEWithSHA1AndDES 
                                       PBEWithSHA1AndTripleDES, PBEWithSHA1AndRC2 
                                       PBEWithSHAAnd40BitRC2, PBEWithSHAAnd128BitRC2 
                                       PBEWithSHAAnd40BitRC4, PBEWithSHAAnd128BitRC4 
                                       PBEWithSHAAnd2KeyTripleDES, PBEWithSHAAnd3KeyTripleDES 
                                       Mars, RC2, RC4, ARCFOUR
                                       RSA, Seal
Key agreement algorithm            : DiffieHellman
Key (pair) generator               : Blowfish, DiffieHellman, DSA, AES, DES, TripleDES, HmacMD5,
                                       HmacSHA1, Mars, RC2, RC4, RSA, Seal, ARCFOUR
Algorithm parameter generator      : DiffieHellman, DSA
Algorithm parameter                : Blowfish, DiffieHellman, AES, DES, TripleDES, DSA, Mars,
                                       PBEwithMD5AndDES, RC2
Key factory                        : DiffieHellman, DSA, RSA
Secret key factory                 : Blowfish, AES, DES, TripleDES, Mars, RC2, RC4, Seal, ARCFOUR
                                       PKCS5Key, PBKDF1 and PBKDF2(PKCS5Derived Key).
```

Below is my code which is giving java.security.InvalidKeyException: Missing password exception.

```
Decrypter(String passPhrase) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyStrength);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "RC4");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHAAnd128BitRC4");
    }

    public String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
        dcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        AlgorithmParameters params = dcipher.getParameters();
        System.out.println("getAlgorithm : "+params.getAlgorithm());
        iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] utf8EncryptedData = dcipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        String base64EncryptedData = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(utf8EncryptedData);
        System.out.println("IV " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(iv));
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data " + base64EncryptedData);
        return base64EncryptedData;
    }

    public String decrypt(String base64EncryptedData) throws Exception {
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] decryptedData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64EncryptedData);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(decryptedData);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }
```

One more question ,Which are the most secure algorithm amoung default java provider because i can not use thrid party like BouncyCastleProvider ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Secure is a bit of a moving target.  Secure against what and for how long.  If you are encrypting transaction data that has no value an hour later, almost anything will do.  If you need to keep something secure for a long time, you want a long key for your PK systems, the longer the better.  But you really pay the price on key generation and some types of stream encryptions/decryptions.

The number one failure of encryption systems is not the algorithm itself, but the implementation of the system, usually how the keys are either generated or stored.  That said, Blowfish and AES are both well regarded and when properly implemented should be everything you need.  I can't recommend http://www.schneier.com/ highly enough.  Applied Cryptography is a bit dated, 10 years or so, but is a cogent explaination of the field specifically geared to programmers.  And his blog is a wealth of information.  Go there and search if you need more details on algorithms.  Won't be a ton of help in java implementation, but you can get that here on SO.